# Download image to my web server using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to download image from url say, `www.someurl.com/images/a.jpg` to server on which my application is running. Can I do this in `javascript` or I have to make web service and call it?

Comment: do you mean to say download as a file?

Comment: Upload image, client to server OR download server to client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. XMLHTTPRequest if you are using plain js or simply use jquery $.get()

Answer (score 1):

In javascript try using this one

```
var a = $("<a>")
    .attr("href", "www.someurl.com/images/a.jpg")
    .attr("download", "img.png")
    .appendTo("body");

a[0].click();
a.remove();
```

Comment: This will download to client machine

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about downloading an image from an external website to your own server, not using the clients browser. Then you might want to check out [node-wget](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-wget), which allows you to very easily download a file from your node.js program:

```
var wget = require('node-wget');
wget(url);
```